# Check if all gameobjects are destroyed

Tags: unity, c#

I am making a shooting game, where I have a countdown as I destroy enemies. I want to implement logic when all the game objects are destroyed within the given time, and the countdown reaches zero.

How do I do that?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to find a way of identifying all objects of interest. Do they have a particular script on them? You simply count them

```
if(GameObject.FindObjectOfType<EnemyScript>()==null)
{
    // Everything destroyed
}
else
{
    // Something survived
}
```

Comment: Note that searching for the objects frequently (eg. every frame) can be quite expensive and slow. It may be better to have the `EnemyScript` increment a shared counter on `Start()` (to say "I am here"), and decrement that counter in `OnDestroy()` (to say "I was shot"). Then you always know the number of active `EnemyScript`s without searching for them every time (handy if you want to display this number in UI, etc). You can have the decrement method check for zero and fire off the "everything destroyed" event in response.

Comment: It can be slow. However I would suggest going with this method and then when you get to a game you are happy with that is the time to profile & optimise. Other solutions are incredibly over engineered and if it turns out the game mode doesn't work as thought it's a few lines to delete. Removing the larger solutions given is going to be far harder. Plus they'll take longer to implement when getting to the game loop is the key here.

Comment: I would consider that a false choice. We can solve this problem in a way that's both simple/fast to author and efficient to run - I've added an answer to demonstrate. It's the same concept described above and in the other answers, just with a drop-in example to show how little code and maintenance is required.

Comment: I think you should carefully study this. Especially point 9 http://howtomakeanrpg.com/a/not-your-problem.html

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you could use `UnityEngine.GameObject.FindObjectOfType<>()` to find all available instances of a particular script, ideally the script that defines these game objects as enemies, in your game. This works, but it involves a lot of redundant work. You do not need to check if there is still an enemy alive in *every* frame. Instead, have your enemies notify us when they are destroyed.

---

### Creating an Objective Manager

Ideally, your main logic would be *aware* of the enemies, and the *enemies* would notify the main logic, when they are destroyed. I usually implement this behavior through a singleton objective manager class.

```
public class ObjectiveManager   
{
    public static ObjectiveManager instance;

    void Awake()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else if(instance != this)
        {
            if(gameObject == null)
            {
                Destroy(this);
            }
            else
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By being created in this way, we can always access our `ObjectiveManager` as an *instance*, even when we do not have a direct reference. That is because we have a *static* reference to our single instance: `ObjectiveManager.instance`. As an alternative to using a singleton and having a static reference to the objective manager, you could provide each enemy with a reference to `ObjectiveManager`.

---

### Creating a list of enemies..

#### .. By searching all game objects

You have *two* fairly easy ways to find all the active enemies in your scene: by *tag* and by *script*. They both work fairly similar to eachother;

- **`FindObjectsOfType<Enemy>()`** will find *all* active instances of `Enemy`, and will retrieve a list of `Object` types.
- **`FindObjectsWithTag("Enemy")`** will find *any* active instance of a game object tagged with the string "Enemy". This allows you to specify specific `Enemy` instances to add to your count, and will retrieve a list of `GameObject` types.

Once you have decided how you wish to create your list, doing so is fairly simple. Note that you should only implement the code relating to the means in wish you wish to create your list.

```
public class ObjectiveManager
{
    public static ObjectiveManager instance;

    public int enemyCount;

    void Awake()
    {
        /* logic for setting up the instance reference */

        Object[] enemyList = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Enemy>();
        GameObject[] enemyList = GameObject.FindObjectsWithTag("Enemy");

        // Since the first element in an array is 0, we will 
        // increment the initial count by 1 to correct the real count.
        enemyCount = (enemyList.Length() + 1);
    }
```

#### .. By having your `Enemy` inform `ObjectiveManager` on `Awake()`

With a singleton objective manager, it is even easier to have the `Enemy` class inform `ObjectiveManager` that it needs to be added to the count. This is especially handy if you wish to add more `Enemy` game objects mid-game.

First, you would add a public method to `ObjectiveManager` to handle incrementing the count.

```
public class ObjectiveManager
{
    public static ObjectiveManager instance;
    public int enemyCount;

    public void AddEnemy()
    {
        enemyCount++;
    }
}
```

Then, on your enemy, add logic to the `Awake()` method to alert the `ObjectiveManager`.

```
public class Enemy
{
    void Awake()
    {
        ObjectiveManager.instance.AddEnemy();
    }
}
```

---

### Alerting `ObjectiveManager` when an enemy is destroyed

From there, you can use the `Enemy` objects `OnDestroy()` method to inform `ObjectiveManager` that it has to decrement `enemyCount` by 1. Assuming we have correctly counted the total enemies at the start, we know that when we kill the last enemy, `enemyCount == 0`.

```
public class Enemy
{
    void OnDestroy()
    {
        ObjectiveManager.instance.EnemyDestroyed();
    }
}

public class ObjectiveManager
{
    public static ObjectiveManager instance;
    public int enemyCount;

    public void EnemyDestroyed()
    {
        enemyCount --;

        if(enemyCount <= 0)
        {
            AllEnemiesDestroyed();
        }    
    }

    public void AllEnemiesDestroyed()
    {
        // all enemies destroyed. Continue appropriate logic from here.
    }
}
```

Comment: This is incredibly over engineered and assumes that the current game concept is what ships. It's adding a large amount of code to a source base which adds maintenance overhead. I would agree with this solution if the question was "How do I optimise my game to remove GameObject.FindObjectOfType<>()" however for getting a game stood up this solution is way over engineered.

Comment: @PompeyPaul, you would say its over engineered, I would say its under-engineered, ultimately it took 5 minutes to write, and if other users want to copy and paste it across to use as a placeholder, it should take substantially less. Ultimately, we strive for *quality* and *depth*, You *are* entitle to your opinion, but the votes do speak for themselves.

Answer (score 2):

There was a complaint that any alternatives to the currently accepted "Find" answer are "over-engineered," but this is not necessarily the case. We can get both good performance and simple code:

```
public class CountedObject : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int count { get; private set; }

    public static event System.Action AllObjectsDestroyed;

    void Start () {
        // Count every object as it's initialized.
        count++;
    }

    void OnDestroy () {
        // Decrement the count when objects are destroyed,
        // and optionally fire an event when the last one is gone.
        if (--count == 0 && AllObjectsDestroyed != null)
            AllObjectsDestroyed();
    }
}
```

Now scripts that are interested in how many objects are left can find out in two ways:

- By reading `CountedObject.count` whenever it needs
- By subscribing to the event `CountedObject.AllObjectsDestroyed += OnAllDestroyed;`

The cost for this is quite modest:

- Very few lines of code
- Constant time to initialize
- Constant time to read the current count

  (for the Find method, this cost is linear in the number of objects in the scene)
- Constant time to destroy
- Constant time per subscriber to notify when the last object is destroyed, and this cost is incurred only when the final destruction happens

  (for the Find method, this cost is linear in the number of objects in the scene *every update tick* that we check it)

This is not as full-featured and robust as an object manager that can track multiple separate object counts or expose more inspector control, but it gets a greater degree of both flexibility and performance than the accepted answer.

We should of course be wary of premature optimization leading us to excessive complexity, but that doesn't mean we should use code we already know is inefficient when there are much better-performing options available with similar code simplicity. In this day of mobile gaming, even if an inefficiency doesn't hit your framerate, it's still sapping the player's battery unnecessarily when there could be a simple way to let them play longer. ;)