# How to change the scene in Unity after all enemies have been killed?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a script that counts how many enemies are left and changes the scene when there are no more enemies. However, it doesn't work, and I can't find the error. I have a really similar script (it's almost the same to be honest) that works perfectly, but I can't figure out how to make this script work.

Here's the code:

```
public class enemyCountt : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int enemiessCount = 5;

    void Start() {}

    void Update(){
        print("Enemy count is " + enemiessCount ); 

        if(enemiessCount <= 0)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene ("bonus");
        }
    }
}
```

and this is attached to the bullet script:

```
if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {
    enemyCountt.enemiessCount --; 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? What happens instead of what you expect? Is the same script attached to more than one scene?

Comment: I want to change the scene when there are no more enemies (when enemiessCount <= 0) but it doesn't happen, it just keep going until the time ends and the game is over. And no, it's not the same script attached in more than one scene

Comment: Throw in a print("something"); line before SceneManager.LoadScene and tell us if it shows up. That will narrow down the problem

Comment: It doesn't show up

Comment: You `print("Enemy count is " + enemiessCount );`; what does it display?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but are you sure `enemyCountt` script is attached to a gameobject in your scene?

Comment: Nothing. I think it should at least display "Enemy count is 5" at the beginning but it doesn't

Comment: If it doesn't display "Enemy count is 5" at the beginning than the Script is not being executed at all. Make sure the Script is attached to whatever GameObject it should be attached to.

Comment: You might find some use in [this earlier question about reacting when all objects of a type have been destroyed](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/132460/check-if-all-gameobjects-are-destroyed)

Comment: I attached it to another GameObject and now it displays "Enemy count is 5" at the beginning but besides that it's still the same

Comment: Is there more to the bullet script? Perhaps the collision method is not getting triggered because it is named incorrectly?

Comment: I suggest renaming your classes such that they start with a capital letter to follow standard naming convention. It won't solve your problem, but it will make your code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 different scripts, so just     enemyCountt.enemiessCount --;    wont work. if both scripts are on the same gameobject, then you can use
     gameObject.enemyCountt.enemiessCount --;

if these arent in the same gameobject, then you can make a reference from the other gameobject with the other script

```
     public GameObject OtherObject;

     void Update(){
     if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {
         OtherObject.enemyCountt.enemiessCount --; 
     }
```

then you have in the object, where you added the script, a free field, where you can drag & drop your GameObject with the script "enemyCountt" and then it should work, but I'm not quite sure

Comment: *`so just enemyCountt.enemiessCount --; wont work`* Yes it will, they've declared `enemiessCount` as being [static](https://stackoverflow.com/a/413904/1663383). There are other small issues with your answer as well, the primary one being that it does nothing to address the asker's comments that their `Update()` method is not running.