# Check if all tagged GameObject are destroyed

Tags: unity, c#

Hello im a total noob so please dont blame me.
So, I have this code but I cant find a fitting answer on how to check if everything tagged "Target1" is destroyed. Most of the answers are either overcomplicated or ,and most certainly, im too stupid

```
public Transform teleportTarget;
public GameObject thePlayer;
public Transform[] spawnLocations;
public GameObject[] whatToSpawnPrefab;
public GameObject[] whatToSpawnClone;

void spawnTargets()
{
    whatToSpawnClone[0] = Instantiate(whatToSpawnPrefab[0], spawnLocations[0].transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0)) as GameObject;
    whatToSpawnClone[1] = Instantiate(whatToSpawnPrefab[1], spawnLocations[1].transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0)) as GameObject;
    whatToSpawnClone[2] = Instantiate(whatToSpawnPrefab[2], spawnLocations[2].transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0)) as GameObject;
    whatToSpawnClone[3] = Instantiate(whatToSpawnPrefab[3], spawnLocations[3].transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0)) as GameObject;
}

private void TeleportPlayer()
{
    thePlayer.transform.position = teleportTarget.transform.position;
}
```

Im just looking for a way to check if all GameObjects Tagged "Target1" (in the whole game)
are destroyed and then to spawnTargets and TeleportPlayer.
Previously I had the bug, that when they respawned it wasnt checking anymore. It has to check all the time.Because else I get stuck, because teleport teleports me all the time. I hope you understand what I mean

I know this is a easy question but im a noob and im sorry for wasting your time, still I hope you can help me.

Comment: You could check if the array's length returned by FindActorsWithTag (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) is 0. Altough it does not say whether they are destroyed, you can deduce that if they are none it is because they were destroyed.

Comment: Did you try implementing the answers to [this related question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/132460/39518)? Where specifically did you run into trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to check if all GameObjects tagged "Target1" have been destroyed, call a function like what you want for example instantiate something and etc...

here is code that you want:

```
void Update(){
    if(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Target1").Length <= 0)
        //call your function to spawn targets and teleports
}
```

Comment: Two considerations here: 1) searching every object in the scene to gather the ones with the right tag, and allocating a new array to return them in, is slightly expensive. Doing this every frame in Update is an unnecessary cost. 2) Do you expect that the return value could ever have a length *less than* zero? The code seems to anticipate this, which may cause confusion since arrays have only non-negative lengths.

Comment: @DMGregory while I agree with most of what you said, it should be noted that FindGameObjectsWithTag doesn’t actually search through _every_ object. In particular it does not look through objects that are untagged. Not that that’s a good reason to use this method.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Ed! Out of algorithmic habit, I'm looking at the big-O style worst case, in which every scene object has a tag. So the upper bound for the search is the entire scene, even if the value in practice can be lower. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend not using tags for this, as searching for matching tags is an unnecessary cost.

Instead, [as I described in this related question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/132460/39518), I'd recommend creating a `MonoBehaviour` that marks the objects you want to count, something like this:

```
public class CountedObject : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int count { get; private set; }

    public static event System.Action AllObjectsDestroyed;

    void Start () {
        // Count every object as it's initialized.
        count++;
    }

    void OnDestroy () {
        // Decrement the count when objects are destroyed,
        // and optionally fire an event when the last one is gone.
        if (--count == 0 && AllObjectsDestroyed != null)
            AllObjectsDestroyed();
    }
}
```

The `static int count` variable is shared among all the marked objects. Every time one enters the scene with `Start()` it increases, and every time one is `Destroy()`ed, it decreases.

The only time you ever need to check if all objects have been destroyed is when actually processing the destruction - we don't need a script checking for it every frame in Update.

Another script that's interested in getting called when the last object has been destroyed can subscribe to the event, like so:

```
CountedObject.AllObjectsDestroyed += OnAllDestroyed;
```

Where `void OnAllDestroyed() { ... }` is the function you want to call once the last object is gone.

If you want to track/display a count, you can access it with no searching or extra computation or memory allocations, just by asking for:

```
CountedObject.count
```

Answer (score 1):

You already seem to keep an array of objects you spawned from the script in `whatToSpawnClone`. So you can use that array to check how many of them are still alive. You can check if a game object is destroyed by comparing it to `null`. GameObject has a special overload for the ==-operator which which returns `true` when you compare a destroyed object to `null`.

Here is a method you can add to the behaviour which contains the code snippet from the question which checks if all the spawned objects are destroyed.

```
private bool AtLeastOneCloneAlive() {
     foreach(GameObject o in whatToSpawnClone) {
         if (o != null) return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```