# How to add multiple transforms to a collection?

Tags: unity, c#

I have an array of Transforms:

```
public Transform[] monsterOne;
```

I can put a child's transform in this array using this code:

```
monsterOne = child.GetComponents<Transform>();
```

But if I try to do this in a loop for each child, the next child just replaces the last one, instead of adding to the array:

```
foreach (Transform child in transform)
{
    monsterOne = child.GetComponents<Transform>();
}
```

How can I add all of these transforms into one collection?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to accomplish here. I'll ask you again: please edit your question to describe what game feature you're trying to make. It looks like there are probably better ways to do this than the code you've shown us, but if we can only see the code - not *why* you're trying to do this at all - then it's hard for us to help.

Comment: Well, I have a GameObject grave in the scene, and this grave is supposed add a monster prefap every 15 seconds, I want to add a limit to monsters number, so i have tried to put the monsters in the 'list' and count many are in the list, so  if there are 4 monsters stop adding prefap monsters

Comment: Then it's much better to ask: "How can I limit the number of monsters my spawner creates?" — ie. ask about what you want to *accomplish*, not about the code you think might accomplish it. This helps you avoid [the X/Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and get better answers than the code you've thought of so far. In this case, you might not need a list at all — [you could ask your monsters to count themselves](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/172634/39518)

Comment: Thank you it works But I'm still curious about my way the X/Y But thank you

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C# can't be appended-onto. What you might want instead is a List, which behaves a lot like an array, but you *can* add items to it:

```
// Declaration of member variable - you can initialize it at the same time.
public List<Transform> children = new List<Transform>();

...

// Populate the list's contents in a method like Start().
foreach(Transform child in this.transform)
{
    children.Add(child);
}
```

You can still access the `i`th item in the collection with `children[i]` or iterate over everything in the collection with `foreach`. The main difference is that if you want to know how many entries are in the collection, you need to use `.Count` with Lists, as opposed to `.Length` with Arrays.

Alternatively, you can pre-size the array to the size you need, then assign each entry one by one:

```
// Declaration of member variable - don't initialize it yet (we don't know the size yet).
public Transform[] children;

...

// Allocate an array of the right size and populate it inside a method like Start().    
int childCount = transform.childCount;
children = new Transform[childCount];

for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
{
    children[i] = transform.GetChild(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every game object can have only one Transform compinent.
You are trying to get multiple Transform components from one transform. Instead you should loop through parent's children. If monsterOne is your Transform of the parent.

Example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < monsterOne.childCount; i++) {
    monsterOne.GetChild(i); //This is the transform of each child in monsterOne 
}
```

Comment: i got eroor "childCount" and "GetChild"

Comment: 'Transform[]' does not contain a definition for 'childCount' and no accessible extension method 'childCount' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Because you are supposed to call those on the parent's Transform. Not on an areay of transforms. In that example monsterOne was the transform of the parent.